# Use avahi in schroot (chroot) environment

Tags: debian, chroot, avahi, schroot

I'm working on debian wheezy and use avahi to communicate with test hardware. For a renewal of the test suite I had to change to a chroot environment (jessie). Is there any possibility to find an 'avahi on chroot' solution, so that I can communicate with the test hardware as before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to solve this issue:

1. In your host machine (wheezy in my case) do:

   `sudo vi /etc/schroot/default/fstab`

   and add the line

   `/var/run/avahi-daemon  /var/run/avahi-daemon       none    rw,bind     0   0`
2. In the chroot environment (jessie in my case) do:

   `sudo apt-get install libnss-mdns`

   and

   `sudo vi /etc/nsswitch.conf`

   there make sure the line for the hosts looks like this:

   `hosts:  files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4`

Comment: Instead of editing the default profile, it might be a better idea to create your own profile and edit it there. `cp -R /etc/schroot/default /etc/schroot/myprofile` and then set `profile=myprofile` in your `schroot.conf`.